# A quick question about reputation recalc

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm more active at *programmers* than here at *meta*, so I'm sure this is just something I missed. However, nothing seems to be poppin' up while searching, so I'll just ask bluntly.

Upon visiting programmers...com/reputation today there was a new button *Trigger reputation recalc*. Upon clicking on it, I gather it got recalculated and on site I lost about 200 reputation.

I don't know what that is about. Can someone point me to the link to the discussion regarding that? Or just give a quick overview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recalc removes any up- or downvotes you got for answers or questions that have been deleted. It also gives you back the one rep you lost for downvoting an answer or question that has then been deleted.

Basically it undoes any changes that a deleted post had on your reputation.

Edit:

Here's the feature request in response to which this feature has been introduced: [Self-instigated rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc)

Comment: Aah, I see. Okey, that makes sense. I was just confused since (obviously) I missed the discussion about it being introduced. Do you perhaps have the link to it?

Comment: Thanks! .......